# Google Sheets radar chart not centering axis in zero

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a Radar Chart using Google Sheets.

[image]

However it insists in not centering in zero and I can't tell what crazy scale it is using in the horizontal axis. Does anyone know if there is a way to center both axis in zero? I tried many different parameters in the chart edition box but couldn't find the right one.

[Example sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_W94pLlj8W2Ay2fEru68uQUu-W04Ad9xfC9E62zu2rI/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using percentages you can "round it" like this:

[image]